# ORA-0020 и как правильно бороться

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

База данных oracl 9i.
Он обслуживает 4-5 программ 24/7,а так же есть в сети ПО общего назначению, где при открытии он сразу ломится ко мне создавая соединение. В итоге у меня под 100 в средне соединений, но активных всего 20-30.

В итоге словил ошибку. После чего база просто поперхнулась и перестала отвечать.пока не перегрузил ее
ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (150) exceeded

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2

ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2

ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2

ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Current SQL statement for this session:

Как я понял, хоть и не активные соединения, но процесс есть и он превысил лимит, а на другие операции начал говорить превысил максимальное количество курсора.

Если я увеличу учитываю формулу
На данный момент запрос select * from v$resource_limit

processes   93  96         150         150
sessions    95  99         170         170

Формула
processes=x

sessions=x*1.1+5

transactions=sessions*1.1

На что мне обратить внимание?
Кака я могу фильтровать соеденения?

Comment: Вроде решение налицо - если есть приложения, которые плодят неактивные соединения, то отключить их, и всё. Какие трудности?

Comment: Программа так написано, что если нет соединения с моей базой, программа виснит. Это очень плохо, поэтому у меня такая ситуация. Изменив данные, Можно в прицюнцепи сделать джоб, что бы проверял конекты, если их много, и неактивны то грохнуть.